# What is the proper notation for vectors that uses only integers? Is it just $\Bbb Z^n$?

Tags: notation, terminology

How do I denote vectors, similar to $\Bbb R^n$, but with integers instead of the reals? Would it just be $\Bbb Z^n$?

If so, then would vectors consisting of exclusively positive integers be $\Bbb Z^{{+n}}$ then? (Because of $\Bbb Z^+$).

Comment: $\Bbb Z^n$ is the standard notation. For positives, usually you'll see $\Bbb N^n$, though some will use the other notation you suggest.

Comment: I find the notation $\mathbb{Z}^{+n}$ confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes $\mathbb{Z}^n$ denotes the set of vectors with integer elements.

This reflects the notation as in the case for the reals, since $$\mathbb{R}^n=\{(a_0,a_1,...,a_n)\mid a_i \in \mathbb{R}\, \text{for each } i\}.$$ 
So similarly $$\mathbb{Z}^n=\{(a_0,a_1,...,a_n)\mid a_i\in \mathbb{Z} \,\text{ for each } i\}.$$
And if we want to restrict to only positive integers, i.e. elements of $\mathbb{Z}_+$, then similarly it would be
$$(\mathbb{Z_+})^n=\mathbb{Z}_+^n=\{(a_0,a_1,...,a_n)\mid a_i\in \mathbb{Z_+} \,\text{ for each } i\}.$$